# The method .setAddress and .setPort in DatagramPacket is not working (?)

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I’m currently working on a server that should retransmit all UDP packets received from one client to another.

This is the code I’m using for the retransmission.

```
// This class contains the Tx and Rx Threads   
public UdpRtxThread(int port, String serverIp) {
this.serverIp = serverIp;
this.port = port;
                
try {
 socketUDP = new DatagramSocket(port);
 socketUDP.setSoTimeout(300);
 socketUDP.setReceiveBufferSize(bufferSize);
                
} catch (SocketException e2) {
 e2.printStackTrace();
 return;
}
                
urx = new UDPRx(socketUDP);
utx = new UDPTx(socketUDP, this.serverIp, this.port);
}

private class UDPTx extends Thread {

private DatagramSocket ds;
private boolean working = true;
private String targetIp;
private int targetPort;

// private DatagramPacket dp;

public UDPTx(DatagramSocket ds, String targetIp, int targetPort) {
    this.ds = ds;
    this.targetIp = targetIp;
    this.targetPort = targetPort;
    this.start();
}

public void closeTxThread() {
    this.working = false;
}

while (working) {
        if (packetsList.size() > 0) {
            try {
                random = rand.nextInt(100);
                System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Random value to prove that is the same thread: "+random);
                
                // Obtain a new UDP packet to be retransmitted
                DatagramPacket packet = packetsList.get(0);
                
                // Check that the destination port and ip specified by the thread is right
                System.out.println("Must be sent to: "+InetAddress
                        .getByName(targetIp)+":"+targetPort+"----> Check random: "+random);
                
                // Set the destination IP and port
                packet.setAddress(InetAddress
                        .getByName(targetIp));
                packet.setPort(targetPort);

                // Check the packet destination
                System.out.println("Sent to: "+packet.getAddress()+":"+packet.getPort()+"----> Check random: "+random);
                
                // send packet
                ds.send(packet);

                //Remove the sent packet from the list
                packetsList.remove(0);
                
                System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
                
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("UDP Tx Thread stopped");
}
```

}

packetsList (ArrayList < DatagramPacket > packetsList) is a list containing all the DatagramPackets received in the reception thread. Once a packet is received, is sent to the retransmission thread and listed in the packetsList. In the transmission thread if the packetsList contains some packet that must be retransmitted, it will change the packet ipaddress and packet port, and then send it to the network.

For some reason that I don’t understand, this process keeps sending the packets to its original source, even changing the destination IP address and port.

Here I provide some of the logs obtained in the server:

---

Random value to prove that is the same thread: 79

Must be sent to: /172.16.112.0:12349----> Check random: 79

Sent to: /172.16.102.95:12352----> Check random: 79

---

---

Random value to prove that is the same thread: 43

Must be sent to: /172.16.112.0:12349----> Check random: 43

Sent to: /172.16.102.95:12352----> Check random: 43

---

---

Random value to prove that is the same thread: 61

Must be sent to: /172.16.112.0:12349----> Check random: 61

Sent to: /172.16.102.95:12352----> Check random: 61

---

---

Random value to prove that is the same thread: 72

Must be sent to: /172.16.112.0:12349----> Check random: 72

Sent to: /172.16.102.95:12352----> Check random: 72

---

---

Random value to prove that is the same thread: 26

Must be sent to: /172.16.112.0:12349----> Check random: 26

Sent to: /172.16.102.95:12352----> Check random: 26

---

---

Random value to prove that is the same thread: 39

Must be sent to: /172.16.112.0:12349----> Check random: 39

Sent to: /172.16.102.95:12352----> Check random: 39

---

---

Random value to prove that is the same thread: 64

Must be sent to: /172.16.112.0:12349----> Check random: 64

Sent to: /172.16.102.95:12352----> Check random: 64

---

---

Random value to prove that is the same thread: 93

Must be sent to: /172.16.112.0:12349----> Check random: 93

Sent to: /172.16.102.95:12352----> Check random: 93

---

Can someone give me a clue about what is happening here?

Thanks for your time and sorry for this messy post!

Comment: Try creating a new packet and give it the userdata of the one from the list and target address.

Comment: By creating a new DatagramPacket it works. 
But why I can't reuse the packet? "new" inside a while is like a memory bomb!

Comment: Can you provide more code? it would be nice to see how the datagramsocket is initialized.

Comment: The requested code has been added